# How to access the text on the screen using pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

The information on this "element" is below:

```
DataItem - 'Title Row 1'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
['DataItem12', 'Title Row 1', 'Title Row 1DataItem']
child_window(title="Title Row 1", control_type="DataItem")
```

When I use .text() it pulls 'Title Row 1'.

I need to pull "Jurat" that is "inside" this element. Is this possible?

[Image of element in the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8UPk.png)

Comment: I think what you searching doesn't exist and retrieve the text of the window. I think what you want is inside an enumeration or a tree. I recommend you to use spy++ (visual studio tool), this tool can tell you what kind of "style" you're trying to reach (Or you can simply enumerate all type inside your window).

Comment: I was about to get it using legacy_properties() which had the "value".

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the value I was looking for using the method legacy_properties() under the tag 'value'. The full list of tags:

'ChildId',
'DefaultAction',
'Description',
'Help':,
'KeyboardShortcut',
'Name',
'Role',
'State',
'Value',

Comment: `.iface_value.CurrentValue` could be another option. In current release method `.get_value()` exists for "Edit" control_type only. It will be fixed later.